# Glue 3.0 has Psycopg2 but "No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'"?

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue 3.0 and am trying to connect to Redshift using Psycopg2. At first I was uploading a whl file version of it and it would give me the error above. I then read that psycopg2 is included in Python 3 so I ran print(help('modules')) and see psycopg2 in the list of modules. I removed external references (whl file) and it still fails. More recently I tried the parameter --additional-python-modules with a value of psycopg2-binary={I don't recall the version} and that failed.

I don't understand why this particular library won't load. I can import mail, numpy, matplotlib etc with no issue... don't know why this one is stubborn. Am I missing something to get psycopg2 that is provided in AWS to load?

Python version
3.7.10 (default, Jun  3 2021, 00:02:01)
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-13)]

Module listing

[image: Excerpt of modules]

Code:

```
import sys
import traceback, boto3
print("Python version")
print (sys.version)
print (help('modules'))
import psycopg2
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Psycopg2 did not show up using `print(help('modules'))` in a my Glue 3.0 Job.

However, adding a Job Parameter did allow me to import it

[image]

```
psycopg2 2.9.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this and in looking at the logs I think calls outside of the VPC are restricted. I appreciate the suggestion.